# C *args parameter

Tags: python, c

Quite simple really;

Let's say I'm writing a function which takes n arguments. In python I could use *args. Is there an equivalent in C?

```py
def foo(int *args):
  for arg in args:
    yield arg
```

```
int foo(*args){ // I know this is a pointer and won't work, but you get the idea
  //do something
}
```

I never ask questions here, but I have searched pretty heavily to find the answer to this but I have come up dry. (Given I haven't seen one yet, I assume that it is a no - in which case, is there an alternative method?).

Comment: C supports [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), such as [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Such functions allow a variable number of arguments.

Comment: While C vararg functions might seem similar, it's not really. IIRC in Python the argument list becomes an actual list. That's not the case in C. In C you need to know the exact number and exact type of all the arguments some way. That's what the formatting specifiers of e.g. `printf` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.

```
int foo(size_t nargs, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   ap = va_start(nargs);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       int arg = va_arg(ap, int);
       // Do something with arg.
   }
   va_end(ap);
}
```

This is more useful when args are not all the same type, like `printf`.

Note that you cannot do:

```
int foo(size_t nargs, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   ap = va_start(nargs);
   int *args = &va_arg(ap, int);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       // do something with args[i];
   }
   va_end(ap);
}
```

This appears to work but can fail because you assumed stack grows downwards.

Comment: Ace. Thanks for the help. Is this all done with the stdarg header?

Comment: @E.Sinclair: Yes, yes it is.